# Windows Phone app display name different from store name

Tags: windows-phone-8, localization, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-store

I would like to give my Windows Phone app a different name on the phone and in the Store (DisplayName should be "blah" and store name should be something like "blah - stuff the app does") but I can't find a way to do that.

I tried to use language resource DLL (as explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/ff967550(v=vs.105).aspx)) but I don't understand how I could give a different store name with this technique.

So, basically, the question is : how does Microsoft choose the name to put in the store? Is it the DisplayName of the app or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the publish app on the dev center, You have to reserve unique app name. You will create app info. So basically, Microsoft does not choose app name. You choose. After that if you change application display name from Package.appxmanifest file, Store name and display name on the phone will be different.

Comment: Yes, i reserved several names (the "blah" and "blah - informations") but I don't understand how I can tell Microsoft that the first one is only for the app's display name and the other one for the store. So if I understand correctly what you're saying, I can't have different names and I should put more infos about the app only on the description part? Am i correct?